# How to call a file download express middleware function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning express and exploring middleware. I am trying to trigger a file download after I hit the root route and send a "Hello World".

So far I have tried.

```
function download(req, res, next) {
  res.download('FILE/Path/Here');
  next();
}

app.get(req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Hello World')
}
```

I have also tried.

```
app.get('/', download, (req, res, next) {
  res.send('Hello World');
}
```

I Know middleware triggers in order but I cant find a way to have the page render first and then the download prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send multiple responses to a single http request

However you can send a HTML page containing JavaScript code which makes another request to the download route to bring up the download prompt in the browser as soon as the page is loaded